# Giving the formula of a line through points in projective geometry

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I'm having some trouble with giving the formula through 2 (or more) points in projective geometry.

For example I have P=(1:0:0), and Q=(1:1:1).

How do I find a formula of a line through these points?

I thought I had to use $ax_0+bx_1+cx_2=0$, but then you get a line

L=   {$(x_0,x_1,x_2)|x_1=x_2=x_3=0$} ?

Or for two points with for example $P=(1:0:0)$ and $Q=(m_1,m_2,m_3)$? Would that be $(1,x,x)$?

Comment: $(1,x,x)$ for any value of $x$.(i.e. $x_0=1$ and $x_1=x_2$) ... avoid $(0,0,0) $!

Comment: If $m_1 \neq 0$ then $Q=(1,\frac{m_2}{m_1},\frac{m_3}{m_1})$ and the equation of the line will be $(1, \lambda \frac{m_2}{m_1},\lambda\frac{m_3}{m_1})$ for any real $\lambda$.

Comment: If $m_1=0$ then the line is $(\lambda,m_2,m_3)$. ... do you have the hang of projective lines now ... I will go on ... If needs be :-)

Comment: I think I get it... so if you'd have $R=(0:1:0)$ and $P=(t_0,t_1,t_2)$ the line through it would be ( if $t_2 \neq 0$) would be ($\frac{\lambda t_0}{t_1},1, \frac{\lambda t_3}{t_1})$?

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{matrix}\\\scriptstyle\text{projective coordinates of }\;P\to \\\scriptstyle\text{projective coordinates of }\;Q\to\end{matrix}\begin{vmatrix}x_0&x_1&x_2\\1&0&1\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Comment: But when you'd plug in $P=(1:0:0)$ here, you would get that $0x_0-x_1+x_2=0$, so you find that $x_1=x_2$, but how would you know that $x_0$=1 and not 0?